# How to use tensorflow ai trained text model in react

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow.js

i have created a simple chatbot model in python from a video tutorial.
Now i have read that i can use this model in react with tendorflow.js lib but i cant get it to run. I searched around a while but i cant find a real working example.

### 1.st the code for creating the model (train)

training.py

```
import random
import json
import numpy as np

import nltk

nltk.download("punkt")
nltk.download("wordnet")
nltk.download('omw-1.4')
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD

import tensorflowjs as tfjs

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()


intents = json.loads(open("./model/Chatbot/intents.json").read())
words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ["?", "!", ".", ","]

for intent in intents["intents"]:
    for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
        word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(word_list)
        documents.append((word_list, intent["tag"]))
        if intent["tag"] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent["tag"])

words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore_letters]

words = sorted(set(words))

classes = sorted(set(classes))

pickle.dump(words, open("./model/Chatbot/words.pkl", "wb"))
pickle.dump(classes, open("./model/Chatbot/classes.pkl", "wb"))

training = []
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)

for document in documents:
    bag = []
    word_patterns = document[0]
    word_patterns = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in word_patterns]
    for word in words:
        bag.append(1) if word in word_patterns else bag.append(0)

    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(document[1])] = 1
    training.append([bag, output_row])

random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)

train_x = list(training[:, 0])
train_y = list(training[:, 1])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation="softmax"))

sgd = SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=sgd, metrics=["accuracy"])

hist = model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=1000, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
model.save("./model/Chatbot/chatbotmodel.h5", hist)
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, "./model/Chatbot/")

print("Done")
```

in the pre-last line the model was exported to model.json and 1 group1-shard1of1.bin file

intents.json (example)

```
{
"intents": [

    {
        "tag": "greeting",
        "patterns": [
            "Hey",
            "Hola",
            "Hello",
            "Hi",
            "Ist da jemand?",
            "Hallo",
            "Guten Tag",
            "Hey",
            "Moin"
        ],
        "responses": [
            "Hallo, schön das du hier bist",
            "Schoen dich wiederzusehen",
            "Hallo, wie kann ich helfen?"
        ],
        "context_set": "greeting"
    }
  ]
}
```

in python i can start now chatbot.py which works

```
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np

import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import load_model

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

intents = json.loads(open("./model/Chatbot/intents.json").read())

words = pickle.load(open("./model/Chatbot/words.pkl", "rb"))

classes = pickle.load(open("./model/Chatbot/classes.pkl", "rb"), fix_imports=True, encoding="ASCII")
model = load_model("./model/Chatbot/chatbotmodel.h5")

context = ""


def clean_up_sentence(sentence):
    sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    sentence_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in sentence_words]
    return sentence_words


def bag_of_words(sentence):
    sentence_words = clean_up_sentence(sentence)
    bag = [0] * len(words)
    for w in sentence_words:
        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            if word == w:
                bag[i] = 1
    return np.array(bag)


def predict_class(sentence):
    bow = bag_of_words(sentence)  # [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]?
    print(np.array([bow]))
    res = model.predict(np.array([bow]))[0]  # [8.58373418e-02 3.18233818e-02 9.12701711e-02 3.93254980e-02...
    print(res)
    ERROR_TRESHOLD = 0.25
    results = [[i, r] for i, r in enumerate(res) if r > ERROR_TRESHOLD]  # Hallo => [[21, 0.35744026]]

    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)  # moin => [[21, 0.35744026]]

    return_list = []
    for r in results:
        return_list.append({"intent": classes[r[0]], "probability": str(r[1])})
    return return_list  # hallo [{'intent': 'greeting', 'probability': '0.35744026'}]


def get_response(intents_list, intents_json):
    tag = intents_list[0]["intent"]  # hallo [{'intent': 'greeting', 'probability': '0.35744026'}] ===> 'greeting'
    list_of_intents = intents_json["intents"]  # ==> alle intents aus datei
    print(intents_list)
    for i in list_of_intents:
        if "context_set" in i:
            context = i["context_set"]
            print(context)
        if i["tag"] == tag:
            result = random.choice(i["responses"])
            break
    return result


print("Go! Bot is running")

while True:
    message = input("")
    ints = predict_class(message)  # # hallo [{'intent': 'greeting', 'probability': '0.35744026'}]
    res = get_response(ints, intents)
    print(res)
```

### 2. Try to get it run in react.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

const url = {
    model: 'https://example.com/model.json',
};

function App() {

async function loadModel(url) {
    try {
        let message = "Hallo";
        //const inputTensor = tf.tensor([parseInt(message)]);
        const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(url.model);
        setModel(model);
        let result = model.predict(message);  // make prediction like in Python
        //let bow = bag_of_words(message)  // [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]?
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    tf.ready().then(() => {
        loadModel(url)
    });
}, [])
```

}

At this point, the model.json and group1-shard1of1.bin are both imported correct, but when i try to model.predict('hallo') i get the following error:

`Error when checking model : the Array of Tensors that you are passing to your model is not the size the the model expected. Expected to see 1 Tensor(s), but instead got 5 Tensors(s).`

Maybe u have an idea to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: maybe something like API ?

Comment: thats the easiest way, yes. but im looking to access the data direct